# form validation not working Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think I am doing everything all right, but why isnt my validation working. Every time the else statement gets executed, even if I enter the valid data.

```
public function login ()
{
    // Redirect a user if he's already logged in
    $dashboard = base_url().'dashboard';
    $this->user_model->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);

    // Set form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

    // Process form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        echo "Validation Success";
    }else{

        $this->session->set_flashdata('validation_errors', validation_errors().'<p>Please enter valid email and password</p>' );
        redirect(base_url().'login', 'refresh');

    }
```

**EDIT**

I am using  dreamhost VPS .

Comment: did you load the form validation library?

Comment: yea the validation library was loaded.

Comment: are html names entered correctly?

Comment: I dont understand , what are html names??

Comment: While you're troubleshooting, I'd temporarily comment out the redirect and use a function call instead, because the redirect hides any error messages that might be showing up.

Comment: check if the form input name in the view are the same in the controlelr form_validation function, maybe you did a typo

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi Hey, the same code is working fine on my linux server

Answer (score 0):

unless you are on another codeigniter project on another server, just use 
`redirect('name_of_controller/name_of_method')` there is no need to put the `base_url()` because it already uses the base url as its condition.

and on your validation message set a message like `$this->form_validation->set_message('rule','message')`

read more at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

And you have not showed us the view, show us how you post the error message on your view.

1.) have a `var_dump()` of your session if the validation errors are really set

2.) have you loaded the session library?

3.) Are you sure you are accessing the proper session variables on the view?

Comment: I am not displaying it with `validation_errors()` function. I am passing the message with the help of session.
I read a article and it said that it might be the problem with the server. But I dont speak `.htaccess`

Comment: And it doesnt answer my question. I am asking about the possible reason why my validation is not working?? Why only the else statement gets executed all the time even if the validation is correct

Comment: @sohanmax02, your view would be helpful, and how are you sure you are setting something on the session? have you tried a var_dump of your session?

Comment: Yea I did. Everything on the session is being displayed. Even the custom message after `validation_errors()` , but the errors in `validation_errors()` are not being displayed

Comment: then show us how you echo it from the view. you still did not show it